# PHP convert an octal characters to string

Tags: php, string, echo, octal, chr

Title is pretty much self explanatory...
How do I echo an octal string ?
I tried :

```
<?php
echo '\047\131\145\141\162\040\072\040\047'.'<br>';
echo decoct('\047\131\145\141\162\040\072\040\047').'<br>';
echo decoct('047').decoct('131').decoct('145').decoct('141').decoct('162').decoct('040').decoct('072'),decoct('040').decoct('047').'<br>';
?>
```

but nothing is working for me....
I'm quite sure that some small tweak is needed here but... which one?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Escape sequences are only processed inside double quoted strings, not single-quoted strings.

```
echo "\047\131\145\141\162\040\072\040\047".'<br>';
```

Answer (score 5):

This a backslash escaped string, so use [`stripcslashes()`](http://php.net/stripcslashes) to un-escape, like this:

```
$escaped = '\047\131\145\141\162\040\072\040\047'.'<br>';
$unescaped = stripcslashes($escaped);
echo $unescaped;
```

Result:

```
'Year : '<br>
```

Answer (score 3):

### This may help

```
function convertOctalToCharacter($octal) {
    return chr(octdec($octal[1]));
}
```

For a mass-tokenizing of strings with octals,
this regex-processing may become handy too:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\([0-7]{1,3})/', 'convertOctalToCharacter', $string);
```

*Credits go to http://www.matthewratzloff.com/ blog post*